# How to recover from broken plugin throwing AbstractMethodError

Tags: java, plugins, exception

I'm modifying a java program to search through a specific folder and load plug-ins at runtime.  The plugin code is working fine.  I have created an UncaughtExceptionHandler to catch problems with plugins that weren't coded properly, and for the most part that works.  Except for one issue (one so far, anyway):

The plugins need to have a class that implements a specific interface, so that the main program recognises them as plugins.  If the developer misses one of the abstract methods, an AbstractMethodError gets thrown.  It goes through my ExceptionHandler and I'm able to put up a message to the user indicating that there's a problem with the plugin.  After that, though, the program just hangs.  What I want is the program to continue going so that I can skip the rest of the plugin stuff, remove it from the plugin list, and let the user run the main program without it.  I put a try/catch block directly around the call to the missing method, but the catch doesn't get executed.  It just goes to the ExceptionHandler and then... I don't know where it goes.

This is my first attempt at exception handling so I'm sure I'm just missing something obvious.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with exceptions that sub-class from the `Error` class is that most of them are not recoverable (in your case it's [AbstractMethodError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AbstractMethodError.html)). As per [the Error class java-doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html):

> An `Error` is a subclass of `Throwable` that indicates serious problems that a reasonable application should not try to catch. Most such errors are abnormal conditions. The ThreadDeath error, though a "normal" condition, is also a subclass of Error because most applications should not try to catch it.

I.e. it's not guaranteed that the app is recoverable after an `Error` is thrown. Depending on how you load/execute that plugin there might be some workarounds. First of all, you could check the loaded plugin class via reflection ([some examples](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classMembers.html)) if there is an implementation of the needed methods before actually trying the exectuion - so you could catch/throw an `Exception` rather than get the `Error` and hang later.

If it's not an option, you could investigate further on what is actually hanging after getting that error by analyzing thread dump re
[Taking thread dumps in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118385/taking-thread-dumps-in-production)