# Stopping tomcat creates thread dumps in catalina.out

Tags: java, tomcat8

When I shutdown tomcat server, a full thread dump OpenJDK is generated. Unfortunately, I have no knowledge about deciphering the thread dump. What could be our issue?

Here's the catalina.out which starts at the line when I stopped the tomcat systemd service - https://gist.github.com/c0debreaker/abd3cb6428bc1c0d5ef394d05af28b0b

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/java.html) a thread dump can be initiated by sending a SIGQUIT to the jvm.

So it may be that your shutdown procedure actually triggers a thread dump - and looking from an operational perspective it does not hurt to do it yet helps a lot in cases where there are problems.

You do not report problems with Tomcat or the application themselves, just asking why you get the thread dump? I'd guess there is something in the shutdown script, so you may want to check the systemd configuration.

Otherwise the webapp itself could also trigger the command and you might want to test your tomcat without a webapp installed.

See also: [Taking thread dumps in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118385/taking-thread-dumps-in-production)

Comment: I bypassed systemd and used startup and shutdown shell scripts. The thread dump still appeared. I found out from another SO post that the reason why it's happening is because of the aws-sdk. Someone in the SO post shared a solution. The link is on my other machine. I'll forward the SO link tomorrow to the developer so he can implement the changes. Thank you.